# Initialization error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/stepexpression/TypeRegistry

Tags: selenium

I am doing the selenium cucumber test for the first time. I get an error when I run the test.

> Initialization error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   io/cucumber/stepexpression/TypeRegistry

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZeUV.png)

[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QynI.png)

POM

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

      <dependency>
       <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
       <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
       <version>4.2.6</version>
   </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-jvm -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-jvm-deps -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.6</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>



    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>   

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Test runner:

```
    package MyRunner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;


@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = ("Features")
        //glue="stepDefinition"
        //format= ("pretty","html:test-output")
      )
public class TestRunner {

}
```

I am using eclipse IDE. I right click the runner > select jUnit to run the test. How can I fix the error so I can run the test?

---

**Update 1**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0-RC2</version>
    </dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>



<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0-RC2</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>13.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java8 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0-RC2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-picocontainer -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0-RC2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-jvm -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0-RC2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

Error:

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   io.cucumber.junit.JUnitCucumberOptionsProvider$JunitCucumberOptions.tags()

---

update 2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFlDB.png)

Comment: Could you please remove the dependencies of group id info.cukes and add io.cucumber's dependencies in your project and then try to run that. Latest version is 5.7.0

Comment: There are many dependencies i have. Which dependency group id should i change to io.cucumber? What version should I use for which dependency?

Comment: It all depends on your requirement but you can visit the below link where I am sure that you will get the latest version of cucumber jars

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber

Comment: This is the first time I am doing cucumber. Currently, I just want to create a simple test and run it. I like to start with navigating to a URL. That would be a good start but I am stuck. Please see the update above.

Comment: No problem my friend. You would have told me before that you are writing it for the first time. Actually I already have a sample project for you. I will share that with you soon. Just check the pom.xml of that project

Comment: Here https://github.com/frostyaxe/ExpediaCucumberSampleTest?files=1 just download this as zip and start looking into it

Comment: Thanks for the sample project. I downloaded it > in Eclipse, imported as maven existing project> I wanted to run it but it errors out. Please see update 2.

Comment: Hello My Friend, I can see that you are using JRE 1.5 instead of that use JDK 1.8 as I have used lambda expressions in that project. Please let me know if you face any issue after changing the JDK

Comment: I am lost here. where do you see I used JRE 1.5?

Comment: Actually it is there in JRE Sytem library. Check some videos on how to change JRE in eclipse :)